# ionic 3 - [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1)

Tags: ionic3

In ionic 3 project I am getting following error when running => ionic cordova build --release android

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNfgu.png)

My Project configuration is as below..

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\APPLE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.2.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
Cordova Platforms  : android 5.1.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.11.0
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : D:\AppData\Android\sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

I don't know whats going wrong...

Comment: are you missing cordova-file-plugin?

Comment: But Ionic program executed without error and proper output is displayed..

Comment: Any solution? @SanchitMahajan

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with http://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-05-27-resolving-android-eacces-error-when-building-ionic-apps-on-a-mac-system/

chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.4/bin/gradle

Change gradle-4.4 to what you have. Fixed on mac

Answer (score 0):

faced same problem while deploying a project in ionic-cordova platforms android/ios

[my terminal error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR5Tx.png)

they are just warnings...
First remove the previous version of java development kit and reinstall it

```
$ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

$ sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_101.jdk
```

Download the dmg from : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Export your jdk to JAVA_home

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<your version>/Contents/Home
```

if still error persists...then install the gradle in that folder....u having been working

```
$ brew install gradle
```

if gradle already installed then..

```
$ brew reinstall gradle
```

my os is currently macosHighSierra..